# Pass parameters to Junit setup method

Tags: java, spring

I have the following base test class which other test classes are going to extend:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BaseControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired 
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws SQLException {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
        Server webServer = Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082");
        webServer.start();
    }
}
```

There are two types of test classes, one that `addFilters` to the `MockMvcBuilders` and other ones that do not `addFilters`. I cannot pass any parameter to `setup`. Is there a way not to create one class for each of these two categories of test classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of those that prefer not to use parent classes for tests. better to use utilities that you include on the setup of your test, so that developers are aware of what these tests are relying on, without needing to navigate through hierarchies to find @Before's , @After's or whatever that might be affecting those tests. Also, with hierarchies you can face very soon issues when you want to combine implementations (you know, multiple parents are not allowed).

Having said that, for the approach you propose, i would just make this Base class abstract and declare an abstract method to identify if the actual test needs those filters or not. setup() then only needs to call that method and do whatever it needs to do. Your tests classes will only need to implement that abstract method (which will basically be a true/false flag).

If you will only have this kind of distinction between your tests, then you can also have 2 more child base classes (childs of the main base class), each one implementing that abstract method in its own way. Your tests can then just extend one of those child base classes and not implement anything.